# Azure Static Web App Deployment Pipeline Error with NX Monorepo

Tags: angular, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to deploy an Angular Application that is inside a Nx Monorepository but I get this error:

> Detecting platforms...

> Could not detect any platform in the source directory.

> Error: Could not detect the language from repo.

[image]

The deployment pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master
- main
- pipeline

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Directory listing'
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/apps/luis
      ls -Rla

- script: |
    cd ./apps/luis/
    npm install --location=global @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
      app_location: "apps/luis"
      api_location: ""
      output_location: "dist/apps/luis"
  env:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```

This is the folder structure:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I fixed the second error by changing the app location to apps/luis/src such that it can find the index.html file. But the first initial error is still not solved.

Comment: Try installing Angular CLI task, instead of script,maybe? and then add 'npm install' task following that?

Comment: nothing changed. I tried with /src now and it works but then the static web app cant resolve the css files loaded in my index.html

Comment: In index.html, how are the path to css files given?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by setting the `app_location` to `"/"`